# Como adicionar um bookmarklet com um favicon especifíco?

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet, favicon, icons, bookmarklet

Fiz um pequeno `script` [bookmarklet](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) e estou tentando adicionar um favicon, mas não consigo.

É nesse bookmarklet que quero implementar um favicon - *keepvid.com*

```
// Juntar a url ativa na barra de endereço, com url destino e redireciona
location.href='http://keepvid.com?url='+location.href;
```

```html
<a href="javascript:location.href='http://keepvid.com?url='+location.href;">keevid : Download</a>
<br>
<p>OJETIVO - Baixar vídeos do "Youtube".</p><p>MODO DE USAR - Adicone na sua barra de favoritos. Abra um vídeo do site "Youtube" e clique no Bookmarklet.</p><p>AVISO - Ainda não há um ícone de identificação para este Bookmarklet.</p>
```

---

[image: O favicon ao lado do título.]

De acordo com a imagem, o favicon que desejo estaria ao lado do título *"KeepVid: ..."*, bem na área circulada de *vermelho*. Eu quero adicionar esse ícone ao *bookmarklet* acima.

**Cito duas fontes de referência no assunto:**

> [adding-favicon-to-javascript-bookmarklet-uses-window-open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952387/adding-favicon-to-javascript-bookmarklet-uses-window-open)
>
> [how-to-have-favicon-icon-set-when-bookmarklet-dragged-to-toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521040/how-to-have-favicon-icon-set-when-bookmarklet-dragged-to-toolbar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neste Q & A, a intenção principal era encontrar um meio de somente fazer a inclusão de um [Favicon](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) no [Bookmarklet](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet). Trago dois Script para tal finalidade em Javascript puro. Vejamos:

## Observer a figura - 1:

[image]

> *Este exemplo, destina-se a setar Favicon definido na Janela e/ou Pop-up*

## Exemplo - A

```
javascript:var pic = document.createElement('link'); pic.setAttribute('rel','shortcut icon');  pic.setAttribute('href','http://keepvid.com/favicon.ico'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(pic);void(0);
```

```html
<a href="javascript:var pic = document.createElement('link'); pic.setAttribute('rel','shortcut icon');  pic.setAttribute('href','http://keepvid.com/favicon.ico'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(pic); void(0);">Adicionar Favicon Pop-Up</a>
```

## Observer a figura - 2:

[image: Se você estiver vendo esta mensagem, é um péssimo sinal de que a image expirou(fora do ar). Mas vamos corrigir esse pequeno detalhe em breve, desculpe-nos pelo transtorno.]

> *Este outro exemplo irá setar Favicon não só no Bookmarklet na Barra de Favoritos/Marcadores, mas também na Barra de endereço e na Aba em uso*

## Exemplo - B

```
javascript: var icone = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];ElementoTemporario = icone.innerHTML;NovoElemento ='<link rel=\'shortcut icon\' href=\'http://keepvid.com/favicon.ico\'>';ElementoTemporario =NovoElemento+ElementoTemporario;icone.innerHTML=ElementoTemporario;
```

```html
<a href="javascript: var icone = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];ElementoTemporario = icone.innerHTML;NovoElemento ='<link rel=\'shortcut icon\' href=\'http://keepvid.com/favicon.ico\'>';ElementoTemporario =NovoElemento+ElementoTemporario;icone.innerHTML=ElementoTemporario;">Adicionar Favicon Favoritos</a>
```

> Para melhor compreensão de todos, o que eu fiz foi acrescentar um novo *elemento* `link` em ambos Script, onde o:

1) **Primeiro** - insere o *favicon* na barra de endereço e na aba ativa

2) **Segundo** - ja insere o *favicon* na barra de endereço, na aba e no *"Bookmaklet"*

Para ficar de fácil entedimento, faça o teste no seu navegador.

Agora cabe adaptar a sua necessidade, caso vá usar com algum serviço terceiro.