# É possível ocultar o redirecionamento, mas manter a ligação para o download?

Tags: javascript, redirecionamento, download

Fiz um simples [favlet](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet), para facilitar a tarefa de conversão de videos do [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/) para áudio:

```html
<a href="javascript:!function(){window.location.href='http://www.youtubeto.com?task=MP3&url='+window.location.href;}();">youtubeto : mp3</a>

<br>

<p> MODO DE USAR - Adicone na sua barra de favoritos. Abra um vídeo do site "Youtube" e clique sobre o Bookmarklet.</p>
```

Agora, quero deixar elegante como uma aplicação. Ao clicar no [favlet](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) localizado na barra de favoritos, gostaria de exibir apenas a janela de download, evitando mostrar o site - http://www.youtubeto.com.

Então pensei inserir no [favlet](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) o método `window.close()` em milissegundos.

```
window.setTimeout (window.close(), 5 * 1000);
```

Mas não funcionou conforme o esperado.

Sei que tem como, pois este serviço online - http://baixar-videos.com/ faz isso. Ele utiliza a infra-estrutura do [youtubeinmp4](http://youtubeinmp4.com/), mas no caso ele **oculta** o site que gera o download.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elaborei utilizando *engenharia reversa*, ou seja, observando e imaginando como seria tal comportamento. Confira logo abaixo como ficou:

```html
<a href="javascript:(function(){var popup = window.open(); URL = 'http://www.youtubeto.com?task=MP3&url='+window.location.href; popup.document.write('<iframe src='+URL+' width=0 height=0 frameborder=0></iframe><script>function fechar(){window.opener = window;window.close()}setTimeout(fechar, 10000)</script>')})()">Youtube MP3</a>

<br><br>

<a href="javascript:(function(){var popup = window.open(); URL = 'http://www.youtubeto.com?task=MP4&url='+window.location.href; popup.document.write('<iframe src='+URL+' width=0 height=0 frameborder=0></iframe><script>function fechar(){window.opener = window;window.close()}setTimeout(fechar, 10000)</script>')})()">Youtube MP4</a>

<br>

<p> Arraste-o para sua barra de favoritos. Abra um vídeo do site "Youtube" e clique sobre o Bookmarklet, aguarde 10 segundos e verá a janela de download e logo em seguida é fechada automaticamente a aba do download.</p>
```

Uma breve explicação sempre é bem-vinda, então vamos lá!

O que estamos fazendo é um **iframe dinâmico em uma janela pop-up**

Aqui temos um `window` trazendo o `iframe width=0 height=0 frameborder=0` em **oculto**.

O temporizador `setTimeout` esta ali para esperar o `load` do site ser iniciado para download.

> **NOTA** - O temporizador esta definido em *10 segundos*. Isso se fez necessário colocar para quem utiliza conexão modesta(*2G ou 3G*), dado que a variação de velocidade oscila demais.
>
> Ja para quem possui *banda larga* cabeada ou via *wireless*, não há necessidade de por número elevado acima de *3 segundos*, o download irá iniciar quase que imediatamente.

Para dar um charme a mais nesse "*bookmarklet*", veja - [Como adicionar um bookmarklet com um favicon especifíco?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138510/como-adicionar-um-bookmarklet-com-um-favicon-especif%C3%ADco)